# Screw hit wire by outlet

Tags: wiring, switch, walls, light

I just hit a wire with a screw by an outlet, I really don't know what I was thinking but I was trying to hit the stud. There was a little popping sound and a spark flew out of where the light switch is (there is no cover on the light switch right now.
Are we going to have to make a hole in the wall to repair this wire? I turned the light switch off for now and am waiting for my husband to get home. I'm just trying to get an idea of what to do next.

Comment: The breaker for that circuit should be turned off.  Don't trust just the light switch.  Wall will need to be opened up for wire repair, since most time there is not enough space to get hands in to do a good job.  The good news is that repairing a wall is much easier than repairing fire damage.

Comment: Make a nice dinner to ease the pain

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you will probably have to make a hole. You've punctured the sheathing and the insulation and probably damaged the conductor. You're probably dealing with a Romex type cable. There are straight splice repair kits but many home stores don't carry them. What's left is adding a junction box where you punched the cable leaving 6" of cable sticking out of the box for splicing a new piece of cable and run that to where the other end of the damaged cable is. That junction box will have to remain accessible. If the junction box doesn't work for you, you'll have to replace the entire run of the cable that you punched.

Comment: Seeing it was near an outlet, might be possible to just move the the outlet, if another cable is not going the opposite way.  Might save needing an extra junction box.

Comment: @crip659 Better yet - replace the single-gang box with a double or triple. Then you can use a standard double or triple plate to cover it up and not have to do *any* drywall work! You can even through an  extra duplex receptacle in there and it will look like it was planned that way.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact   Think the OP hit the wire above(maybe below) the outlet.   I don't get out enough, but think most double/triples are to the sides.  Up/down boxes do make sense, just never saw them, do need to get out more.

Comment: @crip659 Not clear to me from the question - I was thinking to the side since receptacles are typically mounted to a stud. But you are correct - if it is vertical then there are fewer easy fixes.